# How to retrieve cms block?

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block, cms-pages

Deleted row from **Content>Blocks** then I try to add it again from previous backup but it doesn't render on the frontend.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added using block Id then you need to find that Id and replace with new One,Don't use Id, always use identifier.

Hope it will work for you

Comment: I find the id in cms_block but I can't change it because constraints of foreign key with cms_block_store table

Comment: find that cms or xml file where you added that block